# More than one match in file_line

Tags: puppet

```
class tomcat::serverconfig{
  package { 'ntp':
    ensure => installed,
  }

  file_line{ '/etc/ntp.conf': 
    ensure => present,
    path => '/etc/ntp.conf',
    line => 'some-data',
    match => '[/^\s*\n/gm]',
    replace =>true,   
  }
}
```

I want to add a text when I find the first blank line. This code either gives error stating "more than one match found" or would replace all the lines. How to replace only the first match?

Edit: Suggestions to use any other resource welcomed!
      To be clear, I want to replace the first blank line with the text and leave the remaining blank lines untouched.

Comment: Do you want to add the text at the first blank line or replace only the first match? You stated both.

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard, I want to replace the first match (which is a blank line).